# Where can I find the relevant .jar file for com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.Work?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7

I'm unable to import the package named above even with my IDE (Eclipse) configured to use Websphere 7 JVM. 
Did the package change?  Any ideas pls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not part of the JVM, but the server runtime. You can find it in the WAS installation directory under plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar.

Comment: I spent 2 days doing this. And then runtime jar @ plugins folder is right one, fixed above problem!